# Multiple leds lighting on voltage rise

Tags: microcontroller, led, transistors

Ok I know there is a creature out there for this. I have a dc circuit that will be operating between 20-120V dc. I want to put 5 leds in to light in sequence as the voltage rises. It can be breadboarded together or an IC to accomplish this. I am keeping the control system simple with only a multi-turn pot amp for voltage control. This circuit will be driving a permanent magnet dc motor. Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have a low voltage fixed power source available to run the LED circuit? (5 - 12 Volts would be nice...)

Comment: I do, I can add a secondary p.s. for them, keep in mind I want to trigger each led in sequence approx every 20v in circuit v. Rise

Answer (score 1):

The [TI3914](http://www.ti.com/product/LM3914) dot/bar display driver makes this a doddle.

[image]

*Figure 1. A few resistors and a capacitor and, of course, the LEDs is all that's required.*

You need to read the datasheet to figure out how to scale the monitored signal down to an acceptable range for the IC.

Comment: Awesome, I knew there was an IC that would handle this job. Thanks for the help

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer if it fits the bill.